# Firebase pubsub schedule trigger not executing

Tags: javascript, firebase

I have setup a Flutter Firebase project using Cloud Functions pubsub scheduler. I have deployed the function without error but cannot see and mention of the function being executed in the logs.

```
'use strict';

const functions = require("firebase-functions");
const admin = require('firebase-admin');
admin.initializeApp();

exports.scheduleFindDueTasks = functions.pubsub.schedule('every day 12:00').onRun( (context) => {
    console.log("Hello World!");
    functions.logger.info("Hello World!");
});
```